# xslt / jsp syntax (get value from xslt table)

Tags: javascript, jsp, xslt

I have some legacy code needing a slight change, and I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to do it quickly.  I have tried various approaches but have not yet found one that works.

I have an xsl file that defines a page format.  This page includes a table that has a radio button on each row.  The user is supposed to choose one row (via the radio button), then click another button elsewhere on the page to submit an Http request (there are various buttons for different operations).  The parameter for the request always includes the value from column1.

The change I need to make is that for some operations, i also need the value from column2.

The code is currently like this....  In the xls.

```css
 <form name="MyForm">
  <table border="1" frame="border" id="altTable1">

   <tr class="MyTable">

   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="Blah">
   <tr>
    <td> 
     <xsl:element name="input">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">radio</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">column1Name</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">column1Name</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="size">20</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="Column1"/></xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
    </td>    
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Column1"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Column2"/></td>
```

And the jsp is like this:

```html
 var column1Value = "";


 for (i=0, n=parent.frames['bottom'].document.MyForm.elements.length; i<n; i++) {
     if (parent.frames['bottom'].document.MyForm.elements[i].checked) {
          column1Value = parent.frames['bottom'].document.MyForm.elements[i].value;

      }
 }
```

And then they append column1Value as a parameter to the Http request.

I tried adding the following within the xsl element "input", and adding the column2Value logic to the jsp, similar to what it does with column1Value.  I do see the value in the expected place in Fiddler.  But my jsp gets "undetermined" rather than the value I see in Fiddler.

```html
<xsl:attribute name="column2Value"><xsl:value-of select="Column2"/></xsl:attribute>
```

```html
column2Value = parent.frames['bottom'].document.requestorDetailsForm.elements[i].column2Value;
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:  The problem was that jsp had to use getAttribute to access the Column2Value that's embedded within the element.

So the correct jsp is:

```html
column2Value = parent.frames['bottom'].document.requestorDetailsForm.elements[i].getAttribute("column2Value");
```